# How to get a CCSprite to follow users touch with ccTouchMoved

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I want to be able to move certain sprite images with the users touch.
Something along these lines:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint *location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, location)
        {
            sprite.location = ccp(location.x, location.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this doesnt work for me, as there is no tick method running for this method to continually move the CCSprite. I know of the method ccTouchMoved, but I'm unsure how to implement it, any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Only CClayer is able to detect a touches, its automatic. So you are going to need to handle the per tick thing. And it should be ccTouchesMove.. Something like:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"begin");
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{    
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    sprite.position = location;
}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Ended");
}
```

Of course, in your init, you must set `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 2):

You can drag sprite images with the following method in your scene:

```
-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    sprite.position = location;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your code as per below code, it is working for me.

```
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox,location)){
    [sprite setPosition:location];

}
```